# how to create this control/button in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

can someone help me, how to create button/control like that in VB.NET .. that i mean, how to create/use style like that when i pointing the cursor or click the control, the style like transparent. that style different from button style.. please help me.. i have search everywhere but nothing. thank's before

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: is this a WinForm, WebForm, or WPF application?

Comment: i want to create something like that in window application. i've try to create that using button, but the result is different, not like that. please help me

Comment: a windows application could still be `winforms` or `WPF`, could you answer the question as it is a relevant one? `WPF` would be the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: in Windows Form Application sir, can i create it using VB.NET ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish what you are looking for take a look at this example it might help you work out any issues you have:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim myButton As Button = New Button()

    myButton.Text = "Hello World"
    myButton.BackColor = Color.Blue
    myButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.LightBlue
    myButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2

    AddHandler myButton.Click, AddressOf Me.OnMyButtonClick
    AddHandler myButton.MouseHover, AddressOf Me.OnMyButtonEnter
    AddHandler myButton.MouseLeave, AddressOf Me.OnMyButtonLeave

    Panel1.Controls.Add(myButton)

End Sub
```

As you can see I have created a new button, and can modify all of the attributes of the button that you were looking for: Back color, Border color, and Border width, even the content like text or the image. Now you will want to create the events that will perform the actions that you are looking to accomplish:

```
Private Sub OnMyButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim currentButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    currentButton.Text = "I have been clicked!"
    currentButton.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
    currentButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Blue
    currentButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1

End Sub

Private Sub OnMyButtonEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim currentButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    currentButton.BackColor = Color.LightGreen

End Sub

Private Sub OnMyButtonLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim currentButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    currentButton.BackColor = Color.Blue

End Sub
```

As you can see we have defined the 3 events you were looking to capture Mouse Click, Mouse Hover, and Mouse Leave, and within each one we can modify the button as we please. From here you can make a global parameter that monitors the color of the button, or you can monitor the state, from there you can know within each event what you want to do. Take for instance the Mouse Leave event.

You showed that you want to create a border, but have a white background as you can see, all you would have to do is just:

```
myButton.BackColor = Color.White
myButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.LightBlue
```

That's easy enough, but there is one very important part that you need to know. If you want your button to actually perform events, ones that you created, you have to attach them to the button. Lets that a look at this:

```
AddHandler myButton.Click, AddressOf Me.OnMyButtonClick
AddHandler myButton.MouseHover, AddressOf Me.OnMyButtonEnter
AddHandler myButton.MouseLeave, AddressOf Me.OnMyButtonLeave
```

As you can see from the above code you instruct the program what to do when a certain event occurs such as Mouse Click. An important part to do with event handlers is to attach them after creation so that they will perform the actions right away. That is why I placed the attachment of the event handler in the Main() before I added the button to Panel1.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with this:

1. Import your image to resource.

   You will need 3 different image: Normal, Hover and Clicked. Change this to your image name: CustomButtonN, CustomButtonH and CustomButtonC.
2. Add a Class with any name. Then add the code below:

   ```
   Inherits Windows.Forms.Button                                  'To make this class as button command
   Public Sub New()
       Me.FlatStyle = Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat                'Make it flat
       Me.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0                           'With borderless
       Me.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent   'You know this
       Me.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent   'And this
       Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent                           'Transparent key
       Me.ForeColor = Color.Black                                 'Text color
       Me.Width = 32                                              'Button width 
       Me.Height = 32                                             'Button height 
       Me.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.CustomButtonN            'Normal
       Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch             'To stretch the image 
   End Sub
   Private Sub CustomButton_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
       Me.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.CustomButtonC            'Click event
   End Sub
   Private Sub CustomButton_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseHover
       Me.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.MiniButtonH              'Hover event
   End Sub
   Private Sub CustomButton_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeave
       Me.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.CustomButtonN            'Leave even
   End Sub
   Private Sub CustomButton_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
       Me.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.CustomButtonH            'Click release
   End Sub
   ```

   Note: You must compile the project after adding a class or editing:
3. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to start it and then wait for 3 sec, then stop it.
4. Finally see your Toolbox panel click your button name then put to your form.